# GitLab Email not sending?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, debian, gitlab

GitLab should automatically send email to a new user with their password when their account is created.

I have checked the mail.log file and I see no records of sending or attempts to send.
I can send mail via postfix command line with no problems.

In the gitlab ui, I get no fails or anything.  When I look at mailer I see this pending:

```
 Class      Args 

 Notify     ["new_user_email", 8, "qrnq1kSQ"]
```

I've modified gitlab.yml to have the correct from address: notify@mydomain.com

Comment: Also, don't forget to check your spam folder. Gitlab sent me an email, but it was labeled as spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out that I had to run the resque process manually on my server in order for it to process the jobs in the queue.  I'm going to ask another question elsewhere to see how to make that automatic.

The command was:

```
sudo -u gitlab bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=* RAILS_ENV=production BACKGROUND=yes
```

Comment: Hey, cool solution but I didn't get it work for me: I get the following error:

:/home/git/gitlab$ sudo -u git bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=* RAILS_ENV=production BACKGROUND=yes
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'resque:work'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)